# Convert delimited string to array

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have an F# Library I call from C# that reads JSON output and CSV files. The library does processing of the data.

When reading a CSV file to a datatable, I can iterate over the header row like this:

```
let myfile=FSharp.Data.CsvFile.Load(inFile)
let headers=[| myfile.Headers.Value |]
headers.[0]
            |>Seq.iter(fun y-> dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(y)))
```

What I want to do is pass in a pipe-delimited string as a parameter(hdrString) from C# in the event the file does not contain a header. e.g. "Col1|Col2|Col3". I was intending to use match to determine if the string was empty then revert to the file headers by splitting the string. I can't, however, seem to split the string (hdrString.split [ '|' ]) successfully into an string array (string[] []). I've tried split but it gives me an error, essentially, that I can't convert string to obj. I also tried hdrString.ToCharArray() but char[] is not compatible with string[]. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: The appropriate method is using `String.Split`.  You should add the errors you got from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you say you tried `hdrString.split [ '|' ]` where `[ '|' ]` denotes a list of chars, not an array of chars. Try instead:

```
let hdrString = "Col1|Col2|Col3"
hdrString.Split [| '|' |]
```

And probably it's a typo but `.split` is `.Split` (with capital S).